# JTable not updating/refreshing when new model is set with data

Tags: java, swing

Hey so I have a problem with my JTable where it is not updating the table when I set its model to a new one with data within it. I have checked and all the arrays have data values within them, coming from another class. The cData array has all the right strings and values. But it doesnt seem to update. Here is the code, I commented where I think it is going wrong:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DetentionStats extends JPanel
{
    private JLabel title, houseTitle;
    private JPanel leftPanel, rightPanel, dormPanel, housePanel, dormButtonPanel, dormStatsPanel, ADormPanel, BDormPanel, CDormPanel, DDormPanel;
    private JButton ADorm, BDorm, CDorm, DDorm, Update;
    private JTable statsList, houseList;
    private JScrollPane statsListScroll, houseListScroll;
    private final int numberOfColumns = 4;
    private String[] statsColumnNames = {"Name", "Reason"};
    private String[] houseColumnNames = {"Name","Reason","Dorm","Completed"};
    private ArrayList<Detention> completedDetentions;
    private DefaultTableModel statsTable, updateCompleted, houseTable, aDormModel, bDormModel, cDormModel, dDormModel;

    public DetentionStats()
    {

        completedDetentions = new ArrayList<Detention>();

        title = new JLabel("Statistics");
        title.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 24));
        title.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        title.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        ADorm = new JButton("A Dorm");
        DormListener aDormListener = new DormListener();
        ADorm.addActionListener(aDormListener);
        aDormModel = new DefaultTableModel(statsColumnNames, 0);
        ADormPanel = new JPanel();
        ADormPanel.add(ADorm);
        ADormPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 50));
        ADormPanel.setBackground(Color.lightGray);

        BDorm = new JButton("B Dorm");
        DormListener bDormListener = new DormListener();
        BDorm.addActionListener(bDormListener);
        bDormModel = new DefaultTableModel(statsColumnNames, 0);
        BDormPanel = new JPanel();
        BDormPanel.add(BDorm);
        BDormPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 50));
        BDormPanel.setBackground(Color.lightGray);

        CDorm = new JButton("C Dorm");
        DormListener cDormListener = new DormListener();
        CDorm.addActionListener(cDormListener);
        cDormModel = new DefaultTableModel(statsColumnNames, 0);
        CDormPanel = new JPanel();
        CDormPanel.add(CDorm);
        CDormPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 50));
        CDormPanel.setBackground(Color.lightGray);

        DDorm = new JButton("D Dorm");
        DormListener dDormListener = new DormListener();
        DDorm.addActionListener(dDormListener);
        dDormModel = new DefaultTableModel(statsColumnNames, 0);
        DDormPanel = new JPanel();
        DDormPanel.add(DDorm);
        DDormPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 50));
        DDormPanel.setBackground(Color.lightGray);

        dormButtonPanel = new JPanel();
        dormButtonPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2));
        dormButtonPanel.add(ADormPanel);
        dormButtonPanel.add(BDormPanel);
        dormButtonPanel.add(CDormPanel);
        dormButtonPanel.add(DDormPanel);
        dormButtonPanel.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        statsTable = new DefaultTableModel(statsColumnNames, 0);
        statsList = new JTable(statsTable);
        statsListScroll = new JScrollPane(statsList);
        statsList.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(470,260));

        dormStatsPanel = new JPanel();
        dormStatsPanel.add(statsListScroll);
        dormStatsPanel.setBackground(Color.lightGray);

        dormPanel = new JPanel();
        dormPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));
        dormPanel.add(dormButtonPanel);
        dormPanel.add(dormStatsPanel);
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        houseTitle = new JLabel("Completed Detentions");
        houseTitle.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 14));
        houseTitle.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        houseTitle.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);

        Update = new JButton("Update");
        UpdateListener uListener = new UpdateListener();
        Update.addActionListener(uListener);

        houseTable = new DefaultTableModel(houseColumnNames, 0);

        houseList = new JTable(houseTable);
        houseListScroll = new JScrollPane(houseList);
        houseList.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(470,540));

        housePanel = new JPanel();
        housePanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        housePanel.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
        housePanel.add(Update, BorderLayout.EAST);
        housePanel.add(houseTitle, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        housePanel.add(houseListScroll, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        leftPanel = new JPanel();
        leftPanel.add(dormPanel);
        leftPanel.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
        rightPanel = new JPanel();
        rightPanel.add(housePanel);
        rightPanel.setBackground(Color.lightGray);

        add(title, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(leftPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
        add(rightPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);

        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1050,670));
        setBackground(Color.lightGray);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void completeDetention(Detention d)
    {
        completedDetentions.add(d);
        updateCompletedDetentions();
        dormSort();
    }

    private void dormSort()
    {
        Object[][] dData = new Object[completedDetentions.size()][numberOfColumns];
        for(int i = 0; i < completedDetentions.size(); i++)
        {
            Detention d = completedDetentions.get(i);

            if(d.getDorm() == Detention.Dorm.aDorm)
            {
            dData[i][0] = d.getName();

            dData[i][0] = d.getReason();

            aDormModel = new DefaultTableModel(dData, statsColumnNames);
            }
            else if(d.getDorm() == Detention.Dorm.bDorm)
            {
            dData[i][0] = d.getName();

            dData[i][0] = d.getReason();

            bDormModel = new DefaultTableModel(dData, statsColumnNames);
            }
            else if(d.getDorm() == Detention.Dorm.cDorm)
            {
            dData[i][0] = d.getName();

            dData[i][0] = d.getReason();

            cDormModel = new DefaultTableModel(dData, statsColumnNames);
            }
            else if(d.getDorm() == Detention.Dorm.dDorm)
            {
            dData[i][0] = d.getName();

            dData[i][0] = d.getReason();

            dDormModel = new DefaultTableModel(dData, statsColumnNames);
            }
        }
    }

    private void updateCompletedDetentions()
    {
        Object[][] cData = new Object[completedDetentions.size()][numberOfColumns];
        for(int i = 0; i < completedDetentions.size(); i++)
        {
            Detention d = completedDetentions.get(i);
            //-------------------------------------------
            cData[i][0] = d.getName();
            //-------------------------------------------
            cData[i][1] = d.getReason();
            //-------------------------------------------
            if(d.getDorm() == Detention.Dorm.aDorm)
            {
                cData[i][2] = "A Dorm";
            }
            else if(d.getDorm() == Detention.Dorm.bDorm)
            {
                cData[i][2] = "B Dorm";
            }
            else if(d.getDorm() == Detention.Dorm.cDorm)
            {
                cData[i][2] = "C Dorm";
            }
            else if(d.getDorm() == Detention.Dorm.dDorm)
            {
                cData[i][2] = "D Dorm";
            }
            else
            {
                cData[i][2] = "No Dorm Selected";
            }
            //-------------------------------------------

            cData[i][3] = new Boolean(true);
        }

        //this is where it is going wrong (i think)
        updateCompleted = new DefaultTableModel(cData, houseColumnNames);
        houseList.setModel(updateCompleted);
    }

    private class UpdateListener implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
        {
                updateCompletedDetentions();
                dormSort();
        }
    }

    private class DormListener implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
        {
            Object source = event.getSource();
            if(source == ADorm)
            {
                statsList.setModel(aDormModel);
            }
            else if(source == BDorm)
            {
                statsList.setModel(bDormModel);
            }
            else if(source == CDorm)
            {
                statsList.setModel(cDormModel);
            }
            else if(source == DDorm)
            {
                statsList.setModel(dDormModel);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**Runnable example:**

```
public class Table extends JPanel
{
private DefaultTableModel updateTable;
private String[] columnNames = {"Name","Last Name","Location"};
private JTable table;

public Table()
{
    defaultTable = new JTable(columnNames, 0);
    table = new JTable(defaultTable);
}

public void update()
{
    Object[][] data = new Object[array.size()][numberOfColumns];
    for(int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++)
    {
        Detention c = detentionArray.get(i)
        data[i][0] = c.getFirstName();
        data[i][1] = c.getLastName();
        data[i][2] = c.getLocation();
    }

    updateTable = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
    table.setModel(updateTable);
}
}
```

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Ok I will make a runnable example

Answer (score 0):

You might need to use this as last line in  updateCompletedDetentions()  method.

```
fireTableDataChanged();
```

Comment: `updateCompletedDetentions` creates a brand new model which is then applied directly to a `JTable` via the `setModel` method, calling `fireTableDataChanged` is both redundant and generally a bad idea

Comment: yeah I have tried pretty much everything, I have no idea why it doesn't work